# Error "Incomplete type is not allowed" in struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am receiving "Incomplete type is not allowed" error in my c++ code.

My program is to read in student data from the input file, sort names in alphabetical order, and print out sorted names along with its data. The data includes ID numbers and test scores.

The input file includes the repetition of the following:
1. Number of students (which is 16)
2. Number of tests (which is 6)
3. Name of student
4. ID number
5 - 10. Test scores

The output file should include the repetition of the following:
1. Name
2. ID number
3. First test score
4. Average score
5. Letter grade

The following are my lines for struct:

```
struct sGrade 
{ 
    string Name[20]; 
    int IDnum[20]; 
    float scores[5]; 
};
```

But right here, in the mainline, "grade" from the "sGrade grade[size]" line receives that sort of error.

```
string s;
getline(inputf, s);
sizeS = stoi(s);

string t;
getline(inputf, t);
sizeT = stoi(t);

const int size = 16;
sGrade grade[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    getline(inputf, grade[i].Name);
    getline(inputf, s);
    grade[i].IDnum = stoi(s);
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeT; ++j)
    {
        getline(inputf, grade[i].scores);
    }
}
```

What has been written incompletely? Do I have to approach it in another way? Please suggest me some solutions to this.

Thank you!

Comment: DId you `#include <string>` and are `using namespace std`? Also could you provide a minimal reproducable example, which we could compile?

Comment: Yes, I included both of them.

Comment: `string Name[20]` is an array of twenty `string`s. You want either `string Name` or `char Name[20]`.

Comment: Remove all code in which the error stil occures and which should be compilable, maybe then you find the error on your own

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you! I just fixed that part, and the incomplete type error still shows up.

Comment: That's not the only error message you're getting. Unless it's the very first error, you should not care about it at the moment. C++ errors need to be fixed in order of occurrence.

Comment: I appreciate the advice! It's the first error message I'm getting, though, and I don't quite realize what could be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

So there are many problems in the code, mostly around type incompatibilities.

```
getline(inputf, grade[i].Name);
```

means `grade[i].Name` should be a string but it's declared as an array of 20 strings.

```
grade[i].IDnum = stoi(s);
```

means `grade[i].IDnum` should be an `int` but it's declared as an array of 20 ints

```
getline(inputf, grade[i].scores)
```

means `grade[i].scores` should be a string but it's declared as an array of 5 floats.

You have to think more carefully about the types you declare and the names you give things. Do you really want `sGrade` to have 20 names and 20 IDs? Or (more likely) do you really want `sGrade` to have a single name and a single ID, but then declare an array of 20 sGrades?

Here's what I think the code should be, but only you'll know for sure

```
struct sGrade 
{ 
    string Name; 
    int IDnum; 
    float scores[5]; 
}; 

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    getline(inputf, grade[i].Name);
    getline(inputf, s);
    grade[i].IDnum = stoi(s);
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeT; ++j)
    {
        getline(inputf, s);
        grade[i].scores[j] = stof(s);
    }
}
```